# Issue with Checkboxes in Wicket

Tags: wicket

I am finding an issue in getting the checkboxes count that are checked by default using,

item.add(new CheckBox("selected",new PropertyModel(this, "checked")).setEnabled(false));

Any help is appreciated.

My Listview class:

```
ExampleListView(String id, List<Extended> lists, PageParameters params){
protected void populateItem(ListItem<Extended> item)
{
    item.add(new CheckBox("selected",new PropertyModel(this, "checked")).setEnabled(false));
}

             boolean checked= true; 
             public boolean isChecked() { return checked; } 
             public void setChecked(boolean checked) { this.checked = checked; }
```

}

This I need to have the checkbox selected and disabled (kind of read only selected checkbox). In other scenario I also need to have item.add(new CheckBox("selected", new PropertyModel(this, "checked")));

As shown in above code, I introduced, Checked boolean, this displays a selected checkbox in UI, but the selected count list did not get incremented

In My Form class constructor:

```
  public class ExampleForm{

public ExampleForm(String id, List<Extended> list, PageParameters params){

    add(new ExampleListView("Rows", list,params));

     AjaxButton<Void> button= new AjaxButton<Void>("Button"){

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

        for (Extended extn : list) {

            if (((Extended)extn).isSelected()) {       
                selected.add(extn);      
            }
        }
    };
    }

add(button); 
   }
```

}

```
my Html file :

            <input class="simpleLink" wicket:id="selected" type="checkbox"/>

Class file:

    public class Extended  implements Serializable {

                private transient boolean selected = false;

                public boolean isSelected() {
                    return selected;
                }



                public void setSelected (Boolean selected) {
                    this. selected = selected;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I am not sure I really understood what's going on, please provide a more precise example of what you expect. I would say that your Check does not map to any model and you do nothing with your selected attribute coming out of nowhere in your ExampleForm button's implementation.

Comment: I am sorry, it a copy paste mistake. In ExampleListView.java class the line should be -> item.add(new CheckBox("selected",new PropertyModel<Boolean>(this, "checked")).setEnabled(false)); This I need to have the checkbox selected and disabled (kind of read only selected checkbox).  In other scenario I also need to have   item.add(new CheckBox("selected", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(this, "checked")));

Comment: In ExampleListView, I introduced  boolean checked= true;

    public boolean isChecked() {
     return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
     this.checked = checked; }
This displays a selected checkbox in  UI, but the selected count list did not get incremented.

Comment: You should edit your original question, fix any typos, and make sure the code renders properly.  Your ExampleListView class isn't shown and there's some confusion about the number of arguments in the constructor.

Comment: Please read it again and finish editing, there are still problems rendering code in it.

Comment: I dont understand what I need to edit. To me it looks okay.please let me know in specific if you feel anything is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your checked model is the same for all your checkboxes (using a `PropertyModel` mapping to `ExampleListView.checked`), is it by purpose ?

Comment: I am a newbie to wicket, followed some examples in internet and used that inorder to show the checkboxes by default, and added checked attribute in ExampleListView. I used the same "Checked" attribute to show the default check wherever it is required.